# Getting a NullPointer instead of creating a token

Tags: spring-boot, jwt

I'm currently writing a Spring Boot application using JWT. Testing the functionality responsible for creating a token using different dates I encountered a problem. Well, instead of a token I get NullPointer. That's how I test it:

```
@Test
public void testGenerateTokenFromDifferentDates() {
    when(clockMock.now())
            .thenReturn(DateUtil.yesterday())
            .thenReturn(DateUtil.now());

    String token = createToken();
    String tokenLater = createToken();

    assertThat(token).isNotEqualTo(tokenLater);
}

private String createToken() {
    String token = tokenUtil.generateToken(new TestUser(USERNAME));
    return token;
}
```

And this is the class responsible for creating the token:

```
@Component
public class TokenUtil implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3301605591108950415L;
    @Value("${jwt.secret}")
    private String secret;
    private Clock clock = DefaultClock.INSTANCE;
    @Value("${jwt.expires.days}")
    private Long expiration;

    public String getUsernameFromToken(String token) {
        return getClaimsFromToken(token, Claims::getSubject);
    }

    public <T> T getClaimsFromToken(String token, Function<Claims, T> resolverClaims) {
        final Claims claims = getAllClaimsFromToken(token);
        return resolverClaims.apply(claims);
    }

    public String generateToken(UserDetails userDetails) {
        Map<String, Object> claims = new HashMap<>();
        return doGenerateToken(claims, userDetails.getUsername());
    }

    private Claims getAllClaimsFromToken(String token) {
        return Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(secret).parseClaimsJwt(token).getBody();
    }

    private String doGenerateToken(Map<String, Object> claims, String subject) {
        final Date createdDate = clock.now();
        final Date expirationDate = calculateExpirationDate(createdDate);

        return Jwts.builder()
            .setClaims(claims)
            .setSubject(subject)
            .setIssuedAt(createdDate)
            .setExpiration(expirationDate)
            .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, this.secret)
            .compact();
    }

    private Date calculateExpirationDate(Date createdDate) {
        return new Date(createdDate.getTime() + expiration * 1000);
    }
}
```

I can't think what the reason may be. Debugger also doesn't help me because it doesn't come to this moment. Here is the [repository](https://github.com/mmaciula/spring-jwt).
As @theonlyrao suggested here is the stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.github.springjwt.security.jwt.TokenUtil.calculateExpirationDate(TokenUtil.java:59)
at com.github.springjwt.security.jwt.TokenUtil.doGenerateToken(TokenUtil.java:47)
at com.github.springjwt.security.jwt.TokenUtil.generateToken(TokenUtil.java:38)
at com.github.springjwt.security.jwt.TokenUtilTest.createToken(TokenUtilTest.java:42)
at com.github.springjwt.security.jwt.TokenUtilTest.testGenerateTokenFromDifferentDates(TokenUtilTest.java:35)
```

Comment: It would be helpful to see the stacktrace for the NPE, as well as the annotations you have on the test class itself, and how you declare and instantiate `tokenUtil`.

Comment: @theonlyrao I added the stack trace. If you want to see the test class look at the repository https://github.com/mmaciula/spring-jwt/blob/master/src/test/java/com/github/springjwt/security/jwt/TokenUtilTest.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like either `createdDate` or `expiration` are null.

I'm not sure how `createdDate` get instantiated because I've not used that `DefaultClock` library.

I think the issue with `expiration` is that you haven't told Spring where to look for the the application properties in your test. Unless that happening elsewhere in code, you need to specific the path to the resource as described in https://www.baeldung.com/spring-classpath-file-access.

Comment: You were right. The @Value annotation couldn't  load value from application.properties file. I use `ReflectionTestUtils` instead and everything works fine. Thanks for your help.